# Why docker-compose cannot use tabs in JSON-compatible mode?

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, yaml

While using `docker-compose`, I rather using JSON instead of YAML, and according to the [official documentation provided by Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#can-i-use-json-instead-of-yaml-for-my-compose-file), it is possible to use it:

[image]

That said, when I try to run a simple compose-compatible JSON file, it fails with the following output:

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "./sample-file.json", line 2, column 1
```

But, if I replace the tabs with spaces, no matter how many (even without a single space), it starts working:

```
Starting sandbox_apache_1 ... done
Attaching to sandbox_apache_1
apache_1  | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably...
```

In the picture it clearly says "so **any** JSON file", that seems to be untrue.

What is with this, then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL:DR: the `docker-compose` documentation is misleading in quoting a feature of YAML 1.2, when they use an YAML 1.1 based loader to load their `.yml` files.

That things work when you delete the TABs is because you essentially can have very compact JSON: `{"a":[1,2,3]}` without any spaces between nodes at all.

---

Yes YAML is a superset of JSON for all practical purposes, but there are a few things that you need to keep in mind.

First of all you should take documentation that doesn't correctly write the acronym (Yaml instead of YAML) and doesn't directly reference the [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/), but references a non-authorative with a grain of salt. Additionally the [documentation](https://github.com/docker/compose) uses the extension `.yml` for the `docker-compose.yml` file, although the recommended file extension for YAML files, according to the FAQ on yaml.org, has been `.yaml` since Sep 2006.

The specification of YAML 1.2 states that it is intended as a superset of JSON, but `docker-compose` is using PyYAML to parse/load the YAML file and that only loads a subset of YAML 1.1. There were specific changes to YAML going from 1.1 to 1.2 to make YAML 1.2 more of, but not a 100%, superset of JSON.

TAB characters are allowed in YAML 1.2 for white-space, as long as this is not white-space that determines indentation. Since JSON is flow-style YAML, within which indentation should not significant, you can read that as there should be no TAB before the initial `{` or `[`.

In YAML 1.1 the [restriction on using TAB is more severe](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id871856):

> An ignored space character outside scalar content. Such spaces are used for indentation and separation between tokens. To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in these cases, since different systems treat tabs differently.

(i.e. you can have TAB characters in non-plain scalars in YAML 1.1).